# Parallelize window function or speed up window function in spark without changing the windowing logic

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a set of window functions in a spark query which, among other things, partitions on user_num. One of these user_nums has far more rows than the others. This row is getting computed in a single task, which has a much higher shuffle read, shuffle remote read and ultimately takes a huge amount of time.

```
Select LAG(e) OVER (PARTITION BY user_num, a, date ORDER BY time) as aa,
FIRST_VALUE(e)  OVER (PARTITION BY a, date ORDER BY time ROWS
BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) as bbb
FROM table
```

Is there any setting or any way to have this run on different tasks or otherwise shrink this amount of time in a way that would require no or minimal changes to the logic of the window functions?

I.E Could I cache at a certain point, increase number of partitions, increase exec mem etc.

Comment: see in case the data is salted i.e well distributed or not ?

Comment: It is not, one user_id is much larger then the others, but could I salt the user_id without making substantial changes to the window functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things I did that worked here:

1. Change the Window function to a join mimicking the window function. This allowed the computation to be ran in parallel
2. Ultimately the solution I went with was changing First_Value to Last_Value and switching the direction of the order by column. Not sure why this would help, but it went much faster. May have been a bug in the First_Value udf.

FIRST_VALUE(e)  OVER (PARTITION BY a, date ORDER BY time desc ROWS
BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as bbb

Answer (score 0):

One Suggestion to **Scale up by sacrificing some loss in data i.e by increasing the granularity on PARTITION window**.

**Example** :

- Extract the "HOUR" value into a new column from time.
- now PARTITION BY user_num, a, date, HOUR

Now, **your single task will be divided in 24 tasks** .

But this will **bring more NULLS** for your LAG . Example, if you are calculating lag with an offset of 4 , then for every Hour of data you will have 3 NULL values.

So, this is like a **trade off between speed vs accurate data**.

---

You can further increase the granularity to minutes for even more parallelism at the cost of more NULLS.

---

Further improvement interms of loss :

Incase you choose to go with lower granularity, this might affect other "user_nums".
It's better to separate out into 2 dfs :

- separate into 2 dfs (use a group by count and have a threadhold which user_num to consider skewed or you can hardcode, if you think it's fixed.)
- One_with_Skewed_Data
- One_with_normal_Data
- result_from_Skew = One_with_Skewed_Data ..with lower granularity window query
- result_from_normal = One_with_normal_Data .. with your regular query

result = result_from_Skew.union(result_from_normal)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. This was good general advice that I explored before I found a better way by switching the first_value function to last_value